# LWJGL No mentionig of class

Tags: java, c++, lwjgl

in LWGJL all OpenGL functions are spit over classes called GL11, GL21....

I don't want to call the functions like GL11.glVertex3f() but like glVertex3f()

Is there something similar to like C++ (using namespace std)

Comment: They are different versions. No real way.

Comment: is it not possible to have java finding the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ninjacave.com/lwjglbasics3

> Static Import
>
> All OpenGL methods in LWJGL are accessed statically, meaning the class name is present before the method name. Depending on your coding style you may prefer not to type the class name on every OpenGL method. Java's static import feature can be used here to hide the class names.

So, you can do:

```
 import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
```

And use the statically imported version to make the calls:

```
 glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on James's answer if you're using eclipse there is a very convenient way to use LWJGL.  Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Favorites.  Then click 'New Type'.  In the box write org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11  Then when programming you can start typing glVertex or whatever and press ctrl+space.  This will open up a drop down menu with lots of options.  Choose the one you want and it is automatically statically imported for you.  This also just generally speeds up programming.